# Jquery Autocomplete : how to setup what to send to the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Currently, after typing things the server returns me something like :

```
[{"id":"1", "value":"My first character"},{"id":"2", "value":"My second Character"}]
```

And when i'm selecting "My first character", and sumbiting the form, it sends :

```
array(1) { ["members"]=> string(18) "My first character" }
```

*But i'd rather send the ID*. How to tell .autocomplete to send the id instead of the field's label ?
( [JS code](http://pastie.org/private/bfiat4tr4ktxwaiauqboq) )

It must be simple but i'm missing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually if it's a text input you are using you will always submit the displayed value. What you could do is copy the id to an hidden element an then catch that server side. You could do:

```
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                    var terms = split( this.value );
                    // remove the current input
                    terms.pop();
                    // add the selected item
                    terms.push( ui.item.value );
                    // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                    terms.push( "" );
                    this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                    //get the id
                    var id = ui.term.id;
                    //copy it to another hidden element
                    $('#yourhiddeninput').val(id);
                    return false;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks ;-) it works the only flaw is that when i'll add another value, it'll replace the id and it'll not allow multiples values.

Comment: can i make something lie this : $('#yourhiddeninput').val( $('#yourhiddeninput').val() +id ); to make it accept multiple selected values?

Comment: @Tristan You should follow the same logic with the ID that Nicola does with the value in this example (store the IDs comma-separated in the value of the hidden input).

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to add a hidden field to your form that will store the currently selected ID.

```
<input type="hidden" name="memberID" value="" />
```

When an element is selected with Autocomplete, you can use the [`select` event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select) to populate this hidden field with the selected ID.

> Triggered when an item is selected from the menu; ui.item refers to
>   the selected item

Answer (score 0):

In your autocomplete data, add a `label` field and then change the `value` field to the id.

Comment: Just tested that but, as soon as i select my first character it replaces the value by the id which is ugly.