# jQuery UI autocomplete on select input box

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have JSON data feeding `id`, `label` and `value` as keys for values.

When I select data I select the `label`/`value` values onto the textbox `#id_emp_name`. I want to be able to insert the `id` of the `label`/`value` that was selected into the hidden textbox `#id_emp_id`.

My current javascript code:

```
$('#id_emp_name').autocomplete({
    source: '/best_choose/employees.json',
    minLength: 1,
    dataType: 'json',
    max: 12
});
```

Comment: this question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486741/jquery-autocomplete-how-to-setup-what-to-send-to-the-server/7486880#7486880

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the "select" option of autocomplete to define a function to handle selections:

```
$('#id_emp_name').autocomplete({
    source: '/best_choose/employees.json',
    minLength: 1,
    dataType: 'json',
    max: 12, 
    select: function(event, ui) { 
         $('#id_emp_id').val(ui.item.id);
    }
});
```